# Why doesn't the following Core Animation implicit animation work?

Tags: ios, core-animation

The code below is a subclass of `CALayer`. If I call `animateVal`, the `drawInContext` is animated. That's great.

I tried to turn that into an implicit animation with `actionForKey`. If I assign a value to the `val` property (`layer.val = 10`), `val` is changed immediately and `drawInContext` is repeatedly called with the same value of `val`, the one I just assigned, over and over.

What am I doing wrong?

```
@interface MyLayer : CALayer
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat val;
- (void)animateVal:(CGFloat)val;
@end

@implementation MyLayer
@dynamic val;

+ (BOOL)needsDisplayForKey:(NSString *)key {
    return [key isEqualToString:@"val"] || [super needsDisplayForKey:key];
}

- (id<CAAction>)actionForKey:(NSString *)event {
    if ([event isEqualToString:@"val"]) {
        CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"val"];
        anim.duration = 3.0;
        return anim;
    }

    return [super actionForKey:event];
}

- (void)animateVal:(CGFloat)val {
    CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"val"];
    anim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:val];
    anim.duration = 3.0;
    [self addAnimation:anim forKey:nil];
}

- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {

    CGContextAddRect(ctx, CGRectMake(10, 10, self.val, self.val));
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillPath(ctx);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argh.

The solution is to set the *fromValue* when returning the action.

```
    anim.fromValue = [[self presentationLayer] valueForKey:event];
```